# How to use Django forms ModelChoiceField with external database values

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to use a ModelChoiceField to get the values populated from an external database.

I have added an additional database in my setting.py and have set up a externaldb.py file in my app as follows:

```
from django.db import connections

def Location():

    rs = []

    cursor = connections['mydb'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT city FROM db.data_center WHERE removed is null;")
    zones = cursor.fetchall()

        for v in zones[::]:
            rs.append(v)
```

The using python manage.py shell I can do this

```
>>>from platform.externaldb import Location
>>>print Location()
>>>[(u'India-01',), (u'Singapore-01',), (u'Europe-01',)]
```

So I am getting values but how to I get that to appear in a drop down box.. This is my forms.py

forms.py

```
from platform.externaldb import Location

zone = forms.ModelChoiceField(Location(), label='Zone')
```

But this doesn't work for me.. How do I do this so the 3 values appears in the ModelChoiceField drop down list?

Thanks - Oli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) form field rather then the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). The problem with using a `ModelChoiceField` is that it expects a QuerySet. The  `ChoiceField` allows you to add items via a List instead.

```
locations = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Locations(), label="Zone")
```

**EDIT**

Previously, I had used the `ModelChoiceField`:

```
locations = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), label="Zone")
```

which will work as long as `Location` is a Model (which I wasn't sure of based on your code)

Comment: I will try that.. although this seems to work zone = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Locations.objects.all(), label='Zone'). I thought someone posted that but maybe edit their answer. I thought I tried queryset=Locations.objects.all() before but now it works..

Comment: using ModelChoiceField and a queryset doesn't work as my previous comment suggested. I will try the ChoiceField option

Comment: I haven't been able to get forms.ChoiceField(choices=Locations(), label="Zone") to work. I keep getting this error 'too many values to unpack'. I'll keep digging.. but any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like in your original code, the result of `Locations()` (which is used in `choices`) is a list of tuple which is correct, but each tuple needs to be ('key', 'value') which I don't think it is currently. [See here for more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices)

Comment: Brilliant. You were bang on. I updated my sql query to return ID and name and now it works a treat. Originally, it was only returning the name. Thanks very much